# Outlook Add In (PC/MAC/DESKTOP/ONLINE)

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm planning to build my first Outlook Add In. I'm familiar with Outlook VBA, but not with the new technology (javascript).

I want to create one Add In for PC/MAC/DESKTOP/ONLINE to be able to download in the store. Can this be done in one Add In?

Is this the right article to start?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

Comment: That is a good place to start. The starting page that has the overview of the feature is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/outlook-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right avenue. But I'd suggest learning basics of JavaScript/TypeScript, HTML, CSS and etc. basics of web programming first. Web add-ins are not so easy as VBA macros. Here is where you can learn about web add-ins - [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins).